# How to get an object from an array?

Tags: angular

I have an array in which there are a number of records and I want to get from this array only one record by id in the form of an object. But as a result, I get an array from one record.

How can this be fixed?

Result:

```
[{…}]
   0: {id: 1, fname: "Tommie", lname: "Shurtleff", photo: "tommie", money: 667.16}
   length: 1
   __proto__: Array(0)
```

ts:

```
  user: User;
  load() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap(
          (params: Params) => {
            if (params['id']) {
              return this._peopleService.getPeopleById(params['id'])
            }
            return of(null)
          }
        )
      )
      .subscribe(
        (user: User) => {
          this.user = user;
          console.log(this.user)
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
  }
```

service:

```
getPeopleById(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`http://localhost:7000/users?id=${id}`);
}
```

json:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fname": "Tommie",
            "lname": "Shurtleff",
            "photo": "tommie",
            "money": 667.16
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you share `getPeopleById` implementation?

Comment: @RafiHenig Added

Comment: where is the aforementioned array?

Comment: @RafiHenig How to understand where?

Answer (score 1):

How to get an object from an array?
This is the answer

> var yourvariable = array[index]["fieldname"];
> you can use like that in every programming language like that

Answer (score 0):

Just map it to single object on the service level. As far as you only getting particular user for provided 'id', it should be fine.

```
getPeopleById(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(`http://localhost:7000/users?id=${id}`)
            .pipe(map(users => users[0]));

}
```